# kxml is giving a xmlpullparser exception

Tags: java-me, kxml

I checked SO for the xmlpullparser exception but it's giving me others questions with Android and SOUP. I am using J2me and normal HTTPrequest to get my XML and I am using kXMl to parser  the xml text. Below is the code that I am working on. And above it is more parsing code and they work perfectly.

```
if (parser.getName().equals("comments")) {

                        event = parser.next();
                        boolean flag = false;
                        if (parser.getName().equals("comment")) {
                            flag = true;
                            System.out.println("Flag is true");
                        }
                        while (flag) {
                            event = parser.next();
                            Questioncomments.addComponent(new Label(parser.nextText()));
                            event = parser.next();
                            System.out.println("Inside the While");
                            if (!parser.getName().equals("comment")) {
                                flag = false;
                                System.out.println("Flag is false");
                            }
                        }
                        Questioncomments.repaint();
                    }
```

XML I am sending this side - `<comments><comment>Awesome Question @dulitha<idComment></idComment></comment></comments>`

The error is -

> org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: precondition: START_TAG
>   (position:TEXT Awesome Question...@1:399 in
>   java.io.InputStreamReader@f828ed68) 
>           at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.exception(+47)
>           at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextText(+14)
>           at
>   com.petmill.mobile.view.qanda.QuestionCanvas.setData(QuestionCanvas.java:189)
>           at
>   com.petmill.mobile.view.qanda.QuestionsList$5$1$1.actionPerformed(QuestionsList.java:119)

The error comes up at the line where I am trying to get the text - parser.nextText(). How can I parse the xml to get the data required... Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is strange, logging parser.nextText() using Log.i("checks",parser.nextText()); nicely outputs the string we want. However, it is impossible to put the string obtained into a string variable. I have tried the posted solution but without luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not on the `START_TAG` event when you call `parser.nextText().` Check that you are on a START_TAG event when you call `parser.nextText()` with the `parser.getEventType()`. I suspect that you have some whitespace between `<comments>` and `<comment>` tag and therefore your parser is not at the event that you expect it to be.

Perhaps you should also consider a safer approach for parsing this xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
<comments>
          <comment>Awesome Question @dulitha
            <idComment></idComment>
           </comment>
</comments>
```

this is not valid xml

Comment: I changed the XML once again and it gives the same exception